# Appium starting IoS default Map application in iphone4S : specified target process is invalid

Tags: ios, iphone, instruments, appium

I am currently trying to automate (starting the Default MAP-App) on real device (Iphone4S) with Appium.

I have the following code:

```
def setCapabilities():
   desired_caps['platformName'] = 'iOS'
   desired_caps['platformVersion'] = '8.1'
   desired_caps['deviceName'] = 'iPhone4s'
   desired_caps['udId'] = '<phoneUDID>'
   desired_caps['bundleId'] = 'com.apple.Maps'
   appium_url = 'http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub'
   webdriver.Remote(appium_url,desired_caps)
```

I kept getting an exception on the Client side

> "Original error: Instruments crashed on Startup" ,

and on the Server side I have the following error:

> Attempting to run app on real device with UDID -phoneUDID-
>
> "Instruments Usage Error: Specified target process is invalid:
> **com.apple.Maps**"
>
> Instruments exited with code 255

I made sure that the bundleId is the correct one as is defined in the Default BundleId of Iphone, however I kept getting this error. I tried different Default Iphone package (com.apple.safari, com.apple.maps), all returned the same error.

How can I start the apple maps using appium as is written in the code snippet above?

-update : it seems I Need a developer assigned certificate for the app. It means native apps are not possible to be automated (more to be found out..)

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error and have found two reasons that can make this happen:

1. The iOS version is not compatible with your Xcode version, e.g. Xcode 7.3.1 and iOS 10.0.1.
2. If your iOS device runs on 9.x or higher you might have forgot to "trust an Enterprise app" ([Guidelines for installing custom enterprise apps on iOS](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204460))

Just for comparison if needed, this was my trace:

```
[debug] [Instruments] [INST STDERR] Instruments Usage Error: Specified target process is invalid: bundleid.of.my.app

instruments, version 7.3 (60134)

usage: instruments [-t template] [-D document] [-l timeLimit] [-i #] [-w device] [[-p pid] | [application [-e variable value] [argument ...]]]

[debug] [Instruments] Instruments exited with code 255

[Instruments] Error launching instruments: Instruments crashed on startup
```

My device is running under v9.3.4. Xcode version is 7.3.1. Also note that both iOS v10.0.1 and Xcode 8 is not yet supported by latest stable Appium v1.5.3.